# How to prove that the characteristic of domain with identity is either zero or prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra

It is an excise of my textbook of abstract algebra which I can not cope with it.
How to prove that the characteristic of domain with identity is either zero or prime?

Comment: Please provide a reference to the textbook you mention.

Comment: If it is not prime or zero, we can find some composite number $n = n_1 n_2$ so that $n \cdot 1 = 0$ in your domain. Do you see why this results in a contradiction?